# Rails + Amoeba error: Uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amoeba-gem

I need to clone a model in my Rails application and I am using `amoeba` gem to do the same.

```
class Quiz
  belongs_to :scoring
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attempts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :quizzes_test_profiles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :test_profiles, :through => :quizzes_test_profiles
  has_many :evaluations_evaluation_sets, as: :resource

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class EvaluationsEvaluationSet
  belongs_to :test_profile
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :evaluation_set
end
```

I need to clone `Quiz` model with all its nested associations.

```
class QuizzesController
  def duplicate_survey
    id = params[:id]
    original_survey = Survey.find(id)
    respond_to do |format|
      new_survey = original_survey.amoeba_dup
      new_survey.save
      if new_survey
        flash[:notice] = 'Survey successfully cloned.'
      else
        flash[:error]  = 'Survey could not be cloned'
      end
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I execute the above code, I get the following error:

`uninitialized constant Quiz::EvaluationsEvaluationSet`

I do not know where is the mistake here. Please tell me how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

````
```
 amoeba do
   enable
 end
```
````

in Survey model .

Read https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba docs carefully .
if you have clone object with there respective association then you should have to add

```
 amoeba do
    exclude_association
    include_association
    nullify 
  end
```

use such preprocessing directives when cloning the object.

first try with rails console for cloning  the object by using amoeba .

Comment: I have added the `amoeba do enable end` in Quiz model. It is in the question. If I use `include_association` I get `macro` error.

Comment: I think you got error because of  ```has_many :evaluations_evaluation_sets, as: :resource ```  as : resource , something it gone wrong when cloning the  evaluations_evaluation_sets , try to exclude this from cloning .and add ```save!``` when save the  object .